# How to correctly upload images to database Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, google-cloud-storage

In my DRF project I have an image model that stores user uploaded images. I’m also using Googles Cloud Storage to upload the files there. I am successful in uploading the files to the cloud storage but the image doesn’t show up in my admin.

My settings:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backend.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'

GS_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('GS_BUCKET_NAME')
GS_PROJECT_ID = os.environ.get('GS_PROJECT_ID')
GS_LOCATION = os.environ.get('GS_LOCATION')

MEDIA_URL = os.environ.get('MEDIA_URL')
MEDIA_ROOT = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/{}/'.format(GS_BUCKET_NAME)
```

My main project urls.py:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My image model:

```
class BlogImages(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(
        Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_images')
    image = models.ImageField(default=None, null=True,
                              blank=True, upload_to='blog_images/')
```

In my views.py I have this for the images:

```
# Iterate images
            for image in images:

                # Save images to db
                blog_image = BlogImages.objects.create(
                    blog=blog, image=image)
                blog_image.save()
                BlogImagesSerializer(blog_image)

            return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

When I hit the endpoint I get returned a 201 status and it shows an image was created associated with the blog but the image field says there’s no image selected.

Before I integrated and configured cloud storage, it was working fine.